# Makefile error#2 when installing freeradius 2.2.8 eap libeap rlm_eap all modules all src all

Tags: server, 18.04, make

I'm trying to install freeradius 2.2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 and when creating the "make" file, i got the following errors:

Do someone know what should i do or install?

```
Making all in rlm_eap...
/usr/bin/make -w -C rlm_eap all
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap'
Making all in libeap...
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap/libeap'
/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC gcc -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8 -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DNDEBUG -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libltdl -DEAPLIB -I. -I.. -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -c eap_tls.c
 gcc -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8 -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DNDEBUG -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libltdl -DEAPLIB -I. -I.. -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -c eap_tls.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/eap_tls.o
eap_tls.c: In function 'eaptls_success':
eap_tls.c:132:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
            tls_session->ssl->session);
                            ^~
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'eap_tls.lo' failed
make[7]: *** [eap_tls.lo] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap/libeap'
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'libeap' failed
make[6]: *** [libeap] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap'
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'rlm_eap' failed
make[5]: *** [rlm_eap] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src'
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'src' failed
make[1]: *** [src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8'
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The build error you're seeing is because of some type of bug in the code, and that needs fixed by the Freeradius team.

Comment: Seriously? but how did it work for the people in the past? or is it because i am using 18.04? many thanks for the edit and for your answer, i much appreciate it!

Comment: I cannot provide any insights into why this is failing, but as always as libraries change code has to change to adapt to it, so it's possible it's got some changes behind the scenes with SSL libraries or such which're failing.  This said, there **is** a freeradius package in the repositories, is there a reason you want to build from source instead of install what's in the repos already?

Comment: Yep, i need to take over a freeradius server, and i got the config files from the colleague as he will get a new project. There are 20-30 different client files and config settings, so it would be easier if i could run an older version of freeradius and not the new 3.0.19 as his config files are from 2.2.8. I will go on with the 3.0.19 then and try to rebuild from the beginning as i cannot se any other option. Once again Thank you Thomas for your answer and help!

Comment: Perhaps a result of OpenSSL API changes? See for example [freeradius: FTBFS with openssl 1.1.0](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=828305)

Comment: @steeldriver nice find.  That would explain why 2.2.8 doesn't build here for OP.

Comment: If you intend to use FreeRADIUS 2.2.8 you'll need to go back to using 16.04 for now, because it has the older OpenSSL versions and libraries and shouldn't fail to build.  The newer OpenSSL 1.1.0 and 1.1.1 API changes for SSL integration will break 2.2.8 so you can't compile it in newer Ubuntu.

Comment: Many thanks guys! i will go back to 16.04 then.  Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Freeradius 2.2.8 does not build with the OpenSSL APIs of version 1.1.0 or 1.1.1 or newer.  This is documented in [Debian Bug #828305](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=828305).

As a result of this, if you *must* use version 2.2.8, you need to use an Ubuntu with older OpenSSL, which means you're going to be falling back to using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.  That's currently the next older supported release of Ubuntu that might have older OpenSSL libraries available to it.

Failing this, however, if it also fails to build there, you will have to use a later version of FreeRADIUS and manually copy your configuration files, etc. over.  There does come a point where you cannot avoid 'updating' to newer software versions.